# Are my fork processes running parallel or executing one after another?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

I am just going to post pseudo code,
but my question is I have a loop like such

```
for(i<n){
   createfork();
   if(child)
       /*
         Exit so I can control exact amount of forks 
         without children creating more children
        */
       exit
}


void createfork(){
 fork
 //execute other methods
}
```

Does my fork create a process do what it is suppose to do and exit then create another process and repeat? And if so what are some ways around this, to get the processes running concurrently?

Comment: Once forked, the processes both run independently and concurrently.

Comment: [`man 2 fork`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: It depends.  If you have multiple cores, then they run in parallel.  The whole point of a multi-tasking operating system is that it provides the illusion that processes run in parallel on a single processor, so from the only perspective you should care about, they run in parallel.

Comment: @williampursell Yeah I completely understand that and honestly i'd much rather prefer a multi threaded approach rather than multi processed but the application calls for multiple processes, and I need to break it up into at least 6 sections which it technically does. Although if possible I am trying to get them running concurrently.

Comment: 2 processes are running in parallel. Parent and child. Once "execute other methods" returns, child is terminated, and parent forks again. Then OP asks:  "Okay that makes sense that is what I thought was happening, so would using fork in other methods be the only way to get them all running parallel? Is there not a way to do this given a loop?"

Comment: Answer to OP question quoted above. You can fork at the beginning of the loop, call the methods, terminate child and run again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pseudocode is correct as written and does not need to be modified.

The processes are already executing in parallel, all six of them or however many you spawn. As written, the parent process does not wait for the children to finish before spawning more children. It calls `fork()`, checks `if (child)` (which is skipped), then immediately proceeds to the next `for` loop iteration and forks again.

Notably, there's no `wait()` call. If the parent were to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` to wait for each child to finish then that would introduce the serialism you're trying to avoid. But there is no such call, so you're good.

Comment: Thank you, also what I found worked quite well is a break statement for the children. It also in my opinion made the code a lot clearer to read. instead of loading up methods with methods.

Answer (score -1):

When a process successfully performs a POSIX `fork()`, that process and the new child process are initially both eligible to run.  In that sense, they will run concurrently until one or the other blocks.  Whether there will be any periods of time when both are executing machine instructions (on different processing units) depends at least on details of hardware capabilities, OS scheduling, the work each process is performing, and what other processes there are in the system and what they are doing.

The parent certainly does not, in general, automatically wait for the child to terminate before it proceeds with its own work (there is a family of functions to *make* it wait when you want that), nor does the child process automatically wait for any kind of signal from the parent.  If the next thing the parent does is fork another child, then that will under many circumstances result in the parent running concurrently with both (all) children, in the sense described above.

I cannot speak to specifics of the behavior of your pseudocode, because it's pseudocode.