# Does forking in a loop create parallel processes?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork

Just wanted to make sure that I understood forking correctly.
This program creates parallel processes right?

```
void error(char* s){
    perror(s);
    exit(errno);
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
        int reason;
    
        int f = fork();
            switch(f){
                case -1:
                error("fork");
                case 0:
                execl("/bin/echo","echo","y",NULL);
                break;
                default:
                printf("over");
            }
        }
    
}
```

Adding a wait in the parent process would make this serial instead right?

Comment: Each call to `fork` creates a new process that can potentially run in parallel, unless you explicitly force a wait for one to end before forking another.

Comment: Hint: The OS kernel doesn't know it's a loop. For all it knows, maybe you just wrote `fork()` 5 different times.

Comment: If you did (e.g.) `wait(NULL);` after the `default:`, then, yes, it _would_ be serial. The usual for parallel would be a separate loop at the end (e.g.) `while (wait(NULL) >= 0);`

Comment: @CraigEstey What do you mean by seperate loop at the end? As in I'll have a while loop within the for loop? And what would the while loop be doing?

Comment: @Motcho Perhaps I should have said "separate loop _after_ the `for` loop". That is, `/* create all processes */ for (int i = 0;i<5;i++) { ... } /* reap all processes to prevent zombies */ while (wait(NULL) >= 0);`

Comment: @Motcho Ironically, I just did a related answer on this a few hours ago: [Making a process run in the background by using fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74267511/5382650)

Comment: @Motcho, this question is almost identical to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467539